# Find products without an attribute value

Tags: magento-1.8

We have round about 1500 products and some of them has no weight, even though it is a required attribute. I think an import in the past was the mistake...

How can i get all products which don't have a weight?

Answer (score 5):

For NULL values, not empty ones you can also set condition like

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('weight', array('null'=>true)
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$mageProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(*)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('weight'," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use collection to load all the product having attribute with null value

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('weight', array('eq'=>''),
->addFieldToFilter('other_attribute_code', array('eq'=>''), //Repeat this for more attributes

foreach($collection as $product){
    //Do something
    $product->getId();
}
```